# typo3 7 LTS installation database query failed

Tags: mysql, database, typo3

I get following message when trying to first install the **typo3 7.6 LTS version**.

[image: database query error]

I have tried several **new** databases, they are all **empty** and I still keep getting this **error**:

```
**Error:
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'**
```

Comment: Can you please explain the steps you took before you get to the error point?

Comment: After downloading and unzipping the typo3_src-7.6.27.zip I upload it to my FTP and start the installation process over either chrome or ie. Both don't work. I get to step 4 in the process, after selecting my new sql db (empty) and put in the username and password for it. After that in step 4 I put in the username and password for the typo3 website, by clicking continue it seems to reload the page and delete my input. With the next try I get this error message. i have tried deleting and creating a new db several times.

Comment: Does your FTP Server support TYPO3? When you tried to create a new database, did you try with socket or with "Manually configured MySQL TCP/IP connection"? If the second, did you put 127.0.0.1 or "localhost"? Which port did you use?

Comment: Yes, the FTP supports TYPO3. I selected an excisting db and I used manual connection with 127.0.0.1, port 3306

Comment: Did you try to select new Database? The error that you get says that there is already an entry on the tx_extensionmanger with the id 1. That means you ll have to manually delete the entry. It would be better if you created a brand new database. Try it!

Comment: I have tried that, too. Over the typo3 installation and also manually, both do not work.

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Through phpmyadmin or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the whole database and created a new one. It seems something gets added thourghout the installation process. I get this error at step 2 as well now: Redirect loop aborted. If this message is shown again after a reload, your setup is so weird that the install tool is unable to handle it. Please make sure to remove the install[redirectCount] parameter from your request or restart the install tool from the backend navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to empty that table by hand and execute the shown sql query by hand. Maybe you can identify the error.

You also should compare the definition of the table in question.
[image]

maybe your mysql(?) has some problems creating the tables as expected.

Comment: I have already deleted the entry in tx_extensionmanager that showed up by hand. Still the problems persists. I make sure the whole db is empty before I try to install the typo3.

Comment: which version of mysql do you use? is the table generated the same as seen here? has the database, the table and the fields the correct collation?

Comment: My database version is 5.6.14 is and the table looks exactly the same as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the backend by calling the URL, even without making it to step5 (100%) the backend opens up. Step 4/5 would reload and redirect so I tried logging into the backend without finishing to the last step. It seems to work.